# Why does this tf-idf model give 0 similarity?

Tags: python, tf-idf, cosine-similarity, tfidfvectorizer

I have two strings, which are different only slightly:

```
str1 = 'abcdefgh'
str2 = 'abcdef-gh'
```

The only difference is that each sub string has a hyphen. But the tf-idf gives 0 similarity:

Code to compute tf-idf similarity is below:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

def compute_cosine_similarity(str1, str2):
   

    # Create a TF-IDF vectorizer
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

    # Compute the TF-IDF matrix for the two strings
    tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform([string1, string2])

    # Compute the cosine similarity between the two TF-IDF vectors
    similarity_matrix = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[0], tfidf_matrix[1])

    # Extract the similarity score from the matrix
    similarity_score = similarity_matrix[0][0]

    return similarity_score

similar_columns = compute_similar_columns(df1, df2)
```

But if I change to:

```
str1 = 'abcdef-gh'
str2 = 'abcdef-gh'
```

The similarity is 1. It seems that tf-idf does't like some special symbols in one side of the strings, like '-'

Why is that?

Comment: What do you get in the first example if you replace the hyphen by another letter?

Comment: it seems that it is always 0 if the length of the two strings are different. I change it to any other letter, and it is 0 always. Why is that?

Comment: Why should it not be 0 if the strings have different lengths?

Comment: For example, if two strings are slightly different, but they are still very similar. str1 = 'abcdefgh', str2='abcdefg h'. Why is similartiy 0?

Comment: str1 = '05/01/2023'
str2 = '01-05-2023', but this gives similarity as 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine the vocabulary of your fitted Vectorizer instance the scoring makes sense.

```
print(vectorizer.vocabulary_)
-> {'abcdefgh': 1, 'abcdef': 0, 'gh': 2}
```

And in addition the document matrix:

```
print(tfidf_matrix.toarray())
-> array([[0.        , 1.        , 0.        ],
          [0.70710678, 0.        , 0.70710678]])
```

Document `str1` consists of one word, document `str2` of two different words. Therefore the two document vectors do not have any similarity.

However, you can change the analyzer of your Vectorizer from word to character level like so:

```
str1 = 'abcdefgh'
str2 = 'abcdef-gh'

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer="char")
tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform([str1, str2])
similarity_matrix = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[0], tfidf_matrix[1])
similarity_score = similarity_matrix[0][0]

print(similarity_score)
-> 0.8955324150715728
```

This result might be closer to what you expected.